# CH32V003 pin identification

Tags: microcontroller

I want to buy some CH32V's for experimentation. However, in the market i see two different versions. One with 8 pins and one with 20 pins.
What is the difference, ad is there one that is considered the de-facto version?

Answer (score 4):

There are four more characters after the CH32V003 to indicate the exact model.

See the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2302231730_WCH-Jiangsu-Qin-Heng-CH32V003F4U6_C5299908.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In regards to the recent Arduino IDE integration, do you know which one of these chips are supported by the Arduino environment?

Comment: Seems they all are, and others in the CH32 family as well. https://hackaday.com/2024/01/04/ch32-risc-v-mcus-get-official-arduino-support/

Comment: I have used both the SOP8 (J4M6) and the TSSOP20 (F4P6) models and can confirm these are supported. I recommend using the Arduino version 2 IDE which supports debugging, but I've also used 1.8.19 on an older Windows 7 laptop.
Although the Arduino core still needs a bit of TLC to get it to full compatibility, the basics are there and I already had some usable results.